# Getting User signature

Tags: iphone

Him what would be the best way to provide a view where a user can provide their signature, i.e a drawing platform?

Well, how would it be implemented in a view using OpenGL ES?

Comment: Please ask more specific questions.

Comment: Updated to reflect more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, here's the answer:

drawInRect:CGRectMake

From this tutorial http://www.ipodtouchfans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

Answer (score 1):

You should also check out Apple's example program called "GLPaint" since it does exactly this as well.